# Apparent game cancellation in chess.com

Tags: chess.com

Some players, when losing, withdraw the game... without any penalties.

The opponent cancels the game.
It isn't listed in the match history.

There are circumstances when such an abort happens: before a player’s move, or when there is a server reboot.

But in the following game, neither of these situations applies. Has anyone encountered such an event, or knows what might have happened?

[image: example]

---

UPDATE
This is the official answer from chess.com support team:

```
Thank you for reaching out to Chess.com. My name is Golden with the Support Team and I'm here to help.
I'm so sorry about the experience.
I understand that this has become problematic for you while you play games.
We also do not like our players to go through this and we currently have measures in place to prevent and correct these situations. But we know we can do more and we will continue to work on this so that players like you don't have to go through this ordeal.
Please bear with us in the meantime.
Do let me know if you need anything else or have further questions and I'll be happy to help.
```

Comment: chess.com can do whatever they want within the law. As to why they allow this, well it is guesswork unless you wrote the policy document. Hence voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: There is a fundamental question here because the behaviour is paradoxical. It’s very easy to mis-characterize a question as “opinion-based” and we as regulars here should always guard against it, particularly with newcomers who may not know how to craft the wording of questions more carefully

Comment: What is “opinion-based” about the rephrased question?

Comment: It's clear that this game was not canceled before the first move, but I'm not sure how you can say that a server reboot did not happen? Are you seeing this issue frequently on Chess.com, or is this a question about a specific incident that may have been a result of a bug?

Comment: Once a time I see a warning about a pending server reboot. Not in this case and it there are also other cheaters.

Comment: related meta https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/967/are-questions-that-ask-for-help-with-specific-chess-sites-like-chess-com-and-li if you have an opinion, you can voice it there

Comment: @Massimo: I am very sorry that the moderators have decided to continue to close your question. It's very unclear what they are now looking for, since the question has been edited but once a question is closed, it is surprisingly hard to get it reopened. I guess it's human nature in some sense. It would be nice to have a "keep it open" button available at the same time as the "close" button, but it is not. The "reopen" button only appears when a question is closed.

Comment: @Ian Bush, there is no "why" in the amended question, so your earlier rationale for why the question must be "opinion-based" is gone. Please can you explain why the question remains "opinion-based" (so we can fix it), or change your vote, thanks.

Comment: @Laska You don't need "why" in a question to be opinion based, and that is my opinion - for instance consider "Is the current government effective?". Otherwise please reread my comment, which was made well before the edit. I said it is opinion based unless you are the person who wrote the policy document. Somebody presumably privy to that process has replied. Anyway this is the last I have to say on this. I personally think closed on grounds of it being opinion based is perfectly acceptable, and it's no big deal. But that's only my opinion.

Comment: @Ian Bush. I think leaving it open is no big deal, and that should be the default if there is uncertainty. But people don't like to change their minds

Answer (score 2):

TLDR They don't permit it.

Longer answer: I am not sure what you mean by "withdraw" or "cancel" a game. You can abort games, but only on the first move.  Some opponents will simply stop playing and let the clock run out. People who do this consistently get warned and, I think, if they keep doing it, they get banned.

Comment: When a server reboot happens, that will also cause games to be aborted, and I think there may be some warning that a refresh may happen. There are rumours that some secret way of cancelling a game may when it’s in place may also exist, but I have no evidence

Comment: I don't agree about let them quit playing without penalties. The cheaters use this trick to abandon the game everytime they are losing.